# VueJS3 how to import a child component into a parent compent when both components in the same JS file in the Options API mode?

Tags: vue.js

```js
export const ParentCompent = {

    template: `
    <div >Parent Component</div>   
    `
}

export const ChildCompent = {

    template: `
    <div >child Component</div>   
    `
}
```

How to import ChildComponent into the ParentCompent when both components are defined in the same Javascript file?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, they are in the same file so there is no need (or way) for import. Imports are only used when you need to import something from different module (file)

Just use [local registration](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html#local-registration)

```js
export const ChildCompent = {
    template: `<div>child Component</div>`
}

export const ParentCompent = {
    components: {
      ChildCompent 
    },
    template: `<div><div>Parent Component</div><ChildCompent></ChildCompent></div>`
}
```